# How does "ranged" work for effects that don't have an attack roll?

Tags: ranged-attack, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Normally, ranged attacks have 3 range categories (short/medium/long) with different penalties to the attack roll (-0/-2/-5). Which one do you use if an effect doesn't have an attack roll? E.g. an area attack, or a non-attack effect such as Move Object or Create?

Answer (score 3):

On pages 139-140, the various options for the Area Modifier are explained, including the Ranged Modifier. It reads, *"**Ranged** - A Ranged Area Effect can be placed anywhere within the effects range, extending to fill the area's volume from the origin point."* **This means that the effect can be placed anywhere you can accurately see in within the limits of the Ranged Modifier**; for simplicity's sake, lets say that it has to be within the shortest increment (25ft per Rank). If you're using **Create** at a range to drop a considerably large object on someone, I'd argue that such a thing would also count as a Ranged Area Effect as we discussed here. Funny thing about **Move Object** is that it can either be used as a way to use exotic actions at a range (such has picking stuff up or as a medium for tripping people) or as a  "Ranged Strike". When interacting with an opponent using an object that isn't of considerable size, you make a Ranged Attack Roll against their Parry defense; otherwise it should count as a Ranged Area Effect when affecting an opponent.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it does not apply. Area Attacks don't have an attack roll. Dropping an object on someone doesn't have an attack roll. You just use them at maximum range. Move Object is actually an interesting case in my opinion since it ought to be a Ranged attack (unless you take it to Perception range), but I could see an argument for someone using it as a Close attack, much like with Elongation. For Area attacks (including dropping a Created object on someone), you could treat the range penalty as penalty on the Dodge DC so that targets would have an easier time reducing the damage, but that would be a houserule. I could similarly see imposing a range penalty on using Elongation or Move Object to do something at a great distance, like making a skill check in Technology to disarm a bomb from around the corner.